# What to do with barbecue sauce

Tags: culinary-uses, barbecue-sauce

We found a nice recipe lately for barbecue sauce and made 3 variations to test out. The problem is: now we have ~3 pints of homemade barbecue sauce that we need to use before it goes bad. (It won't last nearly as long as store-bought stuff with all of their preservatives).

What are some tasty ways to use up our new sauce?

Comment: Eat lots and lots of meat!

Comment: @yosarrian: don't threaten me with a good time. A meal isn't complete for me until there's something dead on my plate.

Comment: Might wanna make less than a pint of each next time ;)

Comment: @cyberzed: next time, definitely. When I try a recipe the first time though I try not to cut it by more than a half so I was limited by that constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. BBQ sauce pizza w/ chicken, red onion, cheddar/american, etc...
2. As sauce for enchiladas, tacos, quesadilas, etc....
3. BBQ wings.
4. A spicy, cheesy casserole w/ corn, green beans, pasta, etc...
5. Add some to spaghetti sauce for a kick.
6. Obviously, sauce for just about any meat.

Comment: I like the way you think

Answer (score 7):

I like to take a nice center cut pork loin and cook it in a slow cooker (crock pot) for 8 hours in homemade bbq sauce.  When it's done, take it out, use two forks to shred it, then put the shredded pieces back into the sauce to coat.  Mmmm...homemade pulled pork.  Freezes really well in individual portions, too.

Another option is to use it to marinade a nice rack of ribs or three, bake it on a very low temperature for a few hours (or as long as a day), and then grill or broil them to finish.  I'd say the rib meat probably freezes well too - but ribs never last that long in our house!

Comment: nice way to use a bunch of sauce all at once

Comment: I wish I could give you another +1 @stephenmcdonald, just b/c whole pork loins are on sale this week. Phenomenal idea!

Answer (score 3):

The weather is a bit warm for it, but I use bbq sauce in my chili when I make it.

Answer (score 3):

We do ribs in an oven (no grill, but this works great on a grill if you have it) for about 2 hours wrapped in foil, remove foil, and add barbecue sauce at the end to cook on.  We do a spice rub to begin with.  Truly tasty!

Answer (score 3):

We make our own pizzas and one thing we like to do is mix BBQ sauce with the tomato puree to go on the base - gives it a bit of a twist from normal pizza.

Also, often I'll squirt a bit into shepherds or cottage pie with the meat to make it a bit different from normal.

Comment: In Australia, all pizza places have the option of BBQ sauce (mixed with the tomato paste) on every pizza. "BBQ Meat Lover's" is the most popular pizza.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it with barbecue sauce, but I've had good luck freezing other sauces. Could you freeze it in batches large enough for one generous order of barbecued meat?